# Reload/refresh page in browser without re-submitting form?

Tags: php, forms, refresh, reload

I have a form on a php page that is submitted to the same page.
I noticed that if I reload/refresh the page the form gets re-submitted.
How do I code to avoid this in the most easy way?

Comment: You could try redirecting to a refresh page.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: You can't... the whole point is that user input might have been necessary to generate the page you are currently on.  I'd suggest leaving this behavior alone unless you have a specific reason to change it.  If you do, you can do what Blender suggests, and go to an intermediary page, or send your data via AJAX prior to going to the next page.

Comment: You can also generate a random string in a hidden input, put it in a cookie (or session), verify the string corresponds to the cookie's value and destroy it when the form is sent for the first time. So, if the user send the same datas next time, the verification will failed and you know that the form has been already sent. But it requires cookies, so if you can simply redirect, it's the better choice.

Comment: You can use AJAX to submit your form asynchronously if you want to stay on the same page. Other than that most solutions are crude and really a hack rather than an actual solution. Submitting POST data on refresh is a normal browser behavior and there is a reason browsers leave it like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is, to implement the post-redirect-get approach.

Simply said, a POST request will be never delivered to the browser. Instead you execute all necessary actions and store the information you need in the session, and then you make a redirect with code 303.

```
$page = 'show_result.php';
header('Location: '.$page, true, 303);
exit;
```

Doing it this way, the browser will show the "show_result.php" page (a GET request) instead of the page requested with POST. This is also the page that is added to the history, so refreshing and using the back button will never do another POST request. As a nice side effect you get rid of browser warnings about resending data, normally the user cannot decide what to do then anyway.

I think the biggest problem with this approach is, that you need a session to store error messages, that means you have to rely on cookies. If you do no redirect to display errors, the browser will show the warning about resending data.

Comment: Post-redirect-get doesn't require sessions, and I'm not sure what you mean by "a POST request will be never delivered to the browser"

Comment: @j08691 - Every POST request will be answered with a redirect (code 303). The browser receives this answer and starts a new GET request, which shows the result of the first request. The session is necessary when the POST request detects invalid user input, and the following GET request needs to show the error message and the last user input.

Answer (score 3):

This assume a lot of things, but maybe is what you are looking for:

```
if ($_POST)
{
    $success = false;

    /*
     * if all goes OK managing POST data make $success = true;
     * 
     */

    if ($success)
    {
        // this will redirects to your original
        // form's page but using GET method
        // so re-submitting will be no possible
        header("location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `PHP_SELF` will remove any GET parameter. Use `REQUEST_URI` to preserve them.

Answer (score 0):

According to HTTP standard, you ought to make browser to do a GET request after sending POST one.
Here is a sketch example to do the form handling:

```
<?  
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {  

  $err = array();
  //performing all validations and raising corresponding errors
  if (empty($_POST['name']) $err[] = "Username field is required";  
  if (empty($_POST['text']) $err[] = "Comments field is required";  

  if (!$err) {  
    //if no errors - saving data and redirect
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
  }  else {
    // all field values should be escaped according to HTML standard
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
      $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
    }
} else {
  $form['name'] = $form['comments'] = '';  
}
include 'form.tpl.php';
?>
```