# Prevent form from resubmitting upon refresh

Tags: jquery, html

Whenever a user submits my form and then refreshes the page, it resubmits the form.

Here is my stripped down HTML:

```
   <form action="" method="post" id="myform">
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subnewtopic" /> 
   </form>
```

How can I prevent the form from resubmitting upon refresh?

Comment: Didn't you just post the same question? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reload/refresh page in browser without re-submitting form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000798/reload-refresh-page-in-browser-without-re-submitting-form)

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML form is resubmitted when user refreshes page - how do I stop this from happening?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940339/html-form-is-resubmitted-when-user-refreshes-page-how-do-i-stop-this-from-happ)

Answer (score 3):

You need something server-side to handle this. Commonly people use a server-side language (PHP, JSP etc) to handle the post and then redirect to another page. This is a [Post/Redirect/Get  pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (PRG) .

Simply put:

1. The user submits (POSTs) the form.
2. The POST is handled by your (server-side) code that does something with the request data (eg: populates a database) and then REDIRECTs to a new page (eg: thanks.php) or the same page.
3. The page optionally GETs the data (from the db or passed parameter etc) to display to the user.

If the user refreshes the browser they are merely refreshing the thank-you page/view NOT resubmitting anything.

#### JavaScript Alternative..?

Without something server-side (**recommended**) you are going to have to use JavaScript.

<strike>**I would not recommend this**  but if you have no better options you could use JS to set a cookie when the form is submitted unless the cookie already exists - in which case don't submit at all.</strike>

*Something like*:

```js
document.forms["myform"].onsubmit = function(){
    //See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie
    if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)submitted\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
        document.cookie = "submitted=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
        return true;
    } else {
        //cookie exists, dont submit
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" method="post">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

#### Update!

It occurred to me that restricting the form submission if a cookie exists is a bad solution as it does not stop the *refreshing* of the browser but just stops the user using the form more than once. Sorry ;)

**So how to the stop the form being resubmitted if the user refreshes the page?**

To reiterate: **use something server-side.** If you must have a JS solution you could submit the form via AJAX or implement the following simple PRG inspired solution to forward/redirect the page if a certain parameter has been passed (indicating that the form was submitted):

```
<div id="formWrapper">
    <p>Please submit the form</p>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    /* method to fetch params from the query string */
    function getQueryParams() {
        var qs = document.location.search;
        qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
        var params = {}, 
            tokens,
            rx = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
        while (tokens = rx.exec(qs)) {
            params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
                = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
        }
        return params;
    };

    //get the params:
    var params = getQueryParams();

    //test if our 'submitted' param has been passed:
    if(params.submitted){
        //if it has, then reload the page without params
        location = location.protocol+'//'+location.host+location.pathname+"?thanks=true"
    }

    //test if our 'thanks' param has been passed:
    if(params.thanks){
        //if it has been passed we can show the thanks message in place of the form...
        document.getElementById("formWrapper").innerHTML = "Thanks. Your form was submitted and I did something with it. You can refresh this page if you like.";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//Check this out mate!!

//This is working !!!

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
First name: 
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: 
<input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're not adding `event` as a parameter in submit function, this doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: @Ninsly how do you add event as a parameter to submit function? Please post answer.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Simply change `$("form").submit(function(){` to `$("form").submit(function(event){`

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent all form submissions? What about the first form submission that is actually wanted?

Comment: Even if you add the event parameter this totally stops any form submission!

Comment: That is perfectly true, it simply disables the submit button :)